# Does a tallith absolutely require eyelets on each of its corners?

Tags: tzitzis, tallit-gadol, tallit-katan

Does a tallith *absolutely* require eyelets—on each of its corners—where the tzitzith are affixed? Or, *al pi halachah*, may the tzitzith be simply threaded through each corner [with, say, a tapestry needle, for example]?

Which method was more traditionally implemented, in ancient times?

Comment: Eyeletes seems like a lot of work to me for hand needle work